# NTP and phones (need a useful ntp test)

Tags: ntp, wireshark

I have a sip phone which gets its time from  either an ntp server or the asterisk server.

however the packets never seem to get replied to

I put wireshark in the way and looked at anything with protocol ntp  with that i get :

```
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
986 31.590946   172.17.153.201        173.65.167.66         NTP      NTP client

Frame 986 (90 bytes on wire, 90 bytes captured)
Ethernet II, Src: IntelCor_10:0e:8c (00:24:d7:10:0e:8c), Dst: Dell_f7:28:04 (00:18:8b:f7:28:04)
Internet Protocol, Src: 172.17.153.201 (172.17.153.201), Dst: 173.65.167.66 (173.65.167.66) 
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 61200 (61200), Dst Port: ntp (123)
Network Time Protocol

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
   1022 32.586918   172.17.153.201        173.65.167.66         NTP      NTP client

Frame 1022 (90 bytes on wire, 90 bytes captured)
Ethernet II, Src: IntelCor_10:0e:8c (00:24:d7:10:0e:8c), Dst: Dell_f7:28:04 (00:18:8b:f7:28:04)
Internet Protocol, Src: 172.17.153.201 (172.17.153.201), Dst: 173.65.167.66 (173.65.167.66)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 61200 (61200), Dst Port: ntp (123)
Network Time Protocol

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
   1034 33.586195   172.17.153.201        173.65.167.66         NTP      NTP client

Frame 1034 (90 bytes on wire, 90 bytes captured)
Ethernet II, Src: IntelCor_10:0e:8c (00:24:d7:10:0e:8c), Dst: Dell_f7:28:04 (00:18:8b:f7:28:04)
Internet Protocol, Src: 172.17.153.201 (172.17.153.201), Dst: 173.65.167.66 (173.65.167.66)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 61200 (61200), Dst Port: ntp (123)
Network Time Protocol
```

I would like to know how i can test the server (I am currently running windows 7 so net time /set  won't work)  so I can isolate the phones issues as the phone it self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way: In the Windows time settings in the Control panel you can configure an NTP server as a time source. If this works, it should work for the phone as well.